# What is the distribution of $X+Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ come from a bivariate normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Further assume that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is $N(y,1)$ and that the distribution of $Y$ is $N(0,\sigma^2)$. What is the distribution of $X+Y$?

One technique that seems applicable is to note that $X+Y= X-Y+2Y$. If we show that $X-Y$ and $Y$ are independent and determine their parameters (where both must have normal distributions) then we can determine the distribution of $X+Y$ which is normal.

Comment: Characteristic functions are the easiest way (and I guess that X and Y are independent ?).

Comment: Saying "conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is $N(y,1)$" looks equivalent to saying "$X-Y\sim N(0,1)$ for each possible value of $Y$ and so is independent of $Y$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E(X|Y)=Y,\  E(X^2|Y)=1+Y^2,\  E(X^2)=1+\sigma^2.$$
$$E(XY)=E(E(XY|Y))=E(YE(X|Y))=E(Y^2)=\sigma^2.$$
$$E((X+Y)^2)=1+4\sigma^2\Rightarrow X+Y\sim N(0,1+4\sigma^2).$$

Comment: How does does it follow from Var$(X+Y)=1+4\sigma^2$ that $X+Y$ is normally distributed? I think characteristic functions are a safer bet here...

Comment: I think that is because $X$ and $Y$ have a joint bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Ah I overlooked that. Technically you do not need that assumption about the distribution of $(X,Y)$ though. The result also holds only with the assumptions in your question